# How to store pointer to S3 objects in Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to figure out how to store a database consisting of metadata in Amazon SimpleDB, with the actual content the metadata refers to (videos) in S3. As I understand it, I should place a pointer in SimpleDB that refers to the videos in S3. What is this pointer, exactly? Is it the URL of the video located in S3?

Also, are there any code samples that would pertain to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just store the S3 url for the object.

Comment: since I used to come here not founding what I was searching; here's exactly what I wanted: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html Storing an abstract representation of an S3 object which would be ````arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/key_name````.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, just enter the url on simpleDB and you're done.
What you're trying to do is pointed as an use case: http://aws.amazon.com/en/simpledb/usecases_metadata_indexing/

Taking a look at the code library, you can filter by S3 or SimpleDB and you'll find examples like [SimpleDB PHP Sample Program Set](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SimpleDB/3576) and [Travel Log - Sample Java Web Application](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/1264287584622066).

Regards.