# Using Amazon S3 for image storage. Where should I store my Metadata?

Tags: database, amazon-s3, cloud

**Background:**
I am new to cloud computing and large scale DB design. I have to find a storage facility for a large number of images that have a lot of metadata associated with each image. I am going to use Amazon S3 to store my image files and I need a cloud based database solution to store metadata and reference to each image. I need this so I can query a DB for customer request and pull images and their metadata and insert new data as well via some web and mobile application interface I will create.

**Research done:**
I found the S3 is a raw data storage solution. I found many good discussions here on bucket naming conventions and I see many people use S3 as binary storage and use a DB for metadata. I've done some research on mongoDB, dynamoDB, and other database solutions.

**Question:**
I need a direction of where I can find an inexpensive and reliable Database that will work well with Amazon S3, that is ideal for large amount of metadata storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are not looking for a relational DB, why not try http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

and if you want RDMS how about http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: Thank you user2310289. I don't think I need a relational database because I will only have 1 table. I will take a look at simpleDB and see how it can be used in conjunction with S3.

Comment: I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422651/how-to-store-pointer-to-s3-objects-in-amazon-simpledb) that will help me further I believe.

Comment: If you add your own EC2 server you can run your own web services etc as well.  Especially good is the free tier http://aws.amazon.com/free/  PS If you like my answer please mark it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am looking into it right now. Your help is much appreciated!